# How to get the key for a array with his value is equal True

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I'm trying to get all the keys on my Object with a value "T" (true) and show them in the component but i'm getting troubles.

I tried with for and forEach but I can't get the keys.

This is my render method and this is the object

```
render(){
   const races = this.state.data.racesTrack.Races;
        const racesList = [];
}
```

I need to see it like this

```
exacta
hq
place:
quinella
show: 
spr: 
trifecta: 
wps:


  Image with the object: https://i.stack.imgur.com/en09V.png
```

Comment: Can you please paste the object in proper syntax ?

Comment: Added a image with the object

Comment: The problem you are asking is not related to Reactjs and is about the basics of javascript. Just posted an answer for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like this in ES6:

```js
var raceList = []
var races = {
  a: "T",
  b: "F",
  c: "T",
  d: "F"
}

for (key in races) {
  if (races[key] == "T") {
    raceList.push(key)
  }
}

console.log(raceList)
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem you are asking is not related to Reactjs and is about the basics of javascript.

A simpler solution can be using Object Keys Array and the Filter method:

```
var race = {
  a: "T",
  b: "F",
  c: "T",
  d: "F"
}
var sort = Object.keys(race).filter((key)=>{
  return race[key]==='T'
})
console.log(sort)
```

Comment: Could be condensed to `.filter(key => race[key] === 'T')`.